# RoR: Can't change the order of <%= render @post.comments %> and <%= form_for @post.comments.build do |f| %> in view without "NoMethodError"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

When I change the order of

```
<%= render @post.comments %>
```

and

```
<%= form_for @post.comments.build do |f| %>
```

in my view I get an

> NoMethodError at /posts/3 
>  undefined method `name' for
>   nil:NilClass

in

> app/views/comments/_comment.html.erb 
>   `<p><em><%= comment.user.name %></em></p>`

This one is working…

```
  <section class="post-article">
    <%= render @post %> 
  </section>

  <section class="post-comments">
    <h3>Comments<h3>
    <%= render @post.comments %>

    <h4>New Comment</h4>
    <%= form_for @post.comments.build do |f| %>      
      …
    <% end %>

  </section>
```

…this doesn't (changed order of `<%= render @post.comments %>` )

```
  <section class="post-article">
    <%= render @post %> 
  </section>

  <section class="post-comments">

    <h4>New Comment</h4>
    <%= form_for @post.comments.build do |f| %>      
      …
    <% end %>

    <h3>Comments<h3>
    <%= render @post.comments %>

  </section>
```

**Question: Why can I only show the "comment.user.name" when I render the comments above the form_for?**

---

app/views/posts/show.html.erb

```
  <section class="post-article">
    <%= render @post %> 
  </section>

  <section class="post-comments">
    <h3>Comments<h3>
    <%= render @post.comments %>

    <h4>New Comment</h4>
    <%= form_for @post.comments.build do |f| %>

      <%# :body field %>
      <%= f.text_area :body, placeholder: "Text", required: true %>

      <%# :post_id %>
      <%= f.hidden_field :post_id %>

      <%# submit %>
      <%= f.submit class: "button radius tiny success" %>

    <% end %>

  </section>
```

app/views/comments/_comment.html.erb

```
<p><em><%= comment.user.name %> said:</em></p>
<p><%= comment.body %></p>
```

comments_controller.rb

```
class CommentsController < ApplicationController

  def create 
    @comment = current_user.comments.build(comment_params)

    if @comment.save 
      redirect_to post_path(@comment.post_id), 
                  notice: 'Comment was successfully created.'
    else
      redirect_to post_path(@comment.post_id),
                  alert: 'Error creating comment.'
    end
  end

  private
    def comment_params
      params.require(:comment).permit(:body, :post_id)
    end
end
```

posts_controller.rb

```
class PostsController < ApplicationController

  def index
    if current_user
      user_ids = current_user.timeline_user_ids
      @posts = Post.where(user_id: user_ids).order("created_at DESC")
    else
      @posts = Post.all.order("created_at DESC")
    end
  end

  def show
    @post = Post.includes(comments: [:user]).find(params[:id])
  end
end
```

comment.rb

```
class Comment < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :post
  belongs_to :user

  validates :user_id, :post_id, :body, presence: true
  validates :body, length: { maximum: 600 }
end
```

post.rb

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base

  belongs_to :user
  has_many :comments

  validates :user_id, presence: true
  validates :type, presence: true
end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you call `@post.comments.build` a new instance of `Comment` is automatically added to `@post.comments` collection. After that Rails will render `_comment.html.erb` for newly created blank comment which hasn't any `user` associated. That's why the error appears.

To solve the problem you could just slightly change `_comment.html.erb`:

```
<% if comment.persisted? %>
  <p><em><%= comment.user.name %> said:</em></p>
  <p><%= comment.body %></p>
<% end %>
```